# Allowing a function to see listbox in another form

Tags: c++-cli

I have all my code in my .cpp file. I have a function in there:

```
void funct1 (void)    
{
    ...
    if (num_fields) {
        for (ix = 0; ix < num_fields; ix++)
            if (status == OK)
                checkedListBox1->Items->Add(gcnew String(buffer));
    } else
        checkedListBox1->Items->Add("No available extra data fields");
}
```

However my function cannot see the `checkedlistbox1` from my `Form5.h`.

How do I allow my function to see this?

I am calling my function from my cpp file:

```
System::Void Form5::MainMAFBrowseBtn_Click(System::Object^  sender,
        System::EventArgs^  e) {
    checkedListBox1->Items->Clear();
    System::String^ paf_path2 = textBox1->Text;

    FolderBrowserDialog^ folderBrowserDialog1;
    folderBrowserDialog1 = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::FolderBrowserDialog;
    folderBrowserDialog1->Description = L"Select the directory of your MAF files ";
    folderBrowserDialog1->ShowNewFolderButton = false;      

     // Show the FolderBrowserDialog.
    System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1->ShowDialog();
    if ( result == ::DialogResult::OK )
        paf_path2 = folderBrowserDialog1->SelectedPath;
    textBox1->Text = paf_path2;

    paf_path = (char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(paf_path2);

    funct1();
}
```

Comment: If `func1(void)` is part of a class, you must put the class name before the function name (eg. if the class name is `Form5` than in the .cpp file your function definition must look like, `void Form5::funct1(void)`

Comment: Please show the declaration of `checkedListBox1`

Comment: Sorry I am unsure of what you mean I have this in my Form5.h:
this->checkedListBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::CheckedListBox());

Comment: and:
 public: System::Windows::Forms::CheckedListBox^  checkedListBox1;

Comment: Basic OOP, you need a reference to the Form5^ object before you can use any of its members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `functl()` is not part of the class, you'll need to pass in `checkedListBox1` as a parameter, like so:

```
void funct1(System::Windows::Forms::CheckedListBox% checkedListBox1)
{
    ...
}
```

Than in your calling function:

```
System::Void Form5::MainMAFBrowseBtn_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    ...
    functl(checkedListBox1);
}
```

*or* inside your class `Form5` you can put the declaration of `functl` there:

```
class Form5
{
    ...
private:
    void functl();
};
```

Then in your `.cpp` file just declare `functl` as:

```
void Form5::functl()
{
    /// Now you have direct access to checkedListBox1.
}
```